# What is the meaning of "exclusive" and "inclusive" when describing number ranges?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, definition

I see exclusive and inclusive when referring to number ranges.

For example, this is a line from an algorithms book:

> The following function prints the powers of 2 from 1 through n (inclusive).

What is meant by this? What makes a number range inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: When using these numbers inside loops or if-else, use them like : `while(i++ < exclusiveNum)` and `while(i++  <= inclusiveNum)`. :)

Comment: To me it's more like a maths terms than a CS term. When describing a range of sequence, normally we handle the ambiguity of the English "from x to y" by explicitly stating `inclusive` / `exclusive`, to explain if the end points (x or y) is included in the description context. (In maths, it is written as [x,y], (x,y) or [x,y), depending if the ends is included)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> The following function prints the powers of 2 from 1 through n (inclusive).

This means that the function will compute `2^i` where `i = 1, 2, ..., n`, in other words, `i` can have values from 1 up to *and including* the value `n`. i.e n is ***Included*** in ***Inclusive***

If, on the other hand, your book had said:

> The following function prints the powers of 2 from 1 through n (*exclusive*).

This would mean that `i = 1, 2, ..., n-1`, i.e. `i` can take values up to n-1, but *not* including, `n`, which means `i = n-1` is the highest value it could have.i.e n is ***excluded*** in ***exclusive***.

Answer (score 86):

In computer science, inclusive/exclusive doesn't apply to algorithms, but to a **number range** (more specifically, to the endpoint of the range):

```
1 through 10 (inclusive)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 through 10 (exclusive)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

In mathematics, the two ranges above would be:

```
[1, 10]
[1, 10)
```

You can remember it easily:

- **Inclu**sive - **Inclu**ding the last number
- **Exclu**sive - **Exclu**ding the last number

Comment: More pedantically, it applies to the **endpoint** of a range - potentially both the starting and ending one. In mathematics, you would write `[1, 10]` for a closed interval (with both endpoints inclusive), `(1, 10)` for an open interval (with both endpoints exclusive), `[1, 10)` (includes 1, excludes 10), and `(1, 10]` (excludes 1, includes 10). In programming, we are just pragmatically used to all intervals starting with the stated number (inclusive), so that only the ending point is talked about.

Comment: All, understanding the meanings of the brackets and parens notation of the two types of ranges shown above is important.  It helps reduce pesky off-by-one bugs when we're all speaking the same language.

Answer (score 7):

In simple terms, inclusive means within and the number `n`, while exclusive means within and without the number `n`.

Note: that each argument should be marked its "clusivity"/ "participation"

```
# 1 (inclusive) through 5 (inclusive)
1 <= x <= 5 == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# 1 (inclusive) through 5 (exclusive)
1 <= x < 5 == [1, 2, 3, 4]

# 1 (exclusive) through 5 (inclusive)
1 < x <= 5 == [2, 3, 4, 5]

# 1 (exclusive) through 5 (exclusive)
1 < x < 5 == [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm wondering what is the word for this exclusivity/exclusivity, and "clusivity" is a curious candiate!

Answer (score 3):

The value of n inclusive 2 and 5 [2,5]
including both the numbers. In case exclusive, only the first is included.

Programming terms n >= 2 && n <= 5:

The value of n exclusive of 2 and 5 [2,5)

n>=2 && n<5

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Why is it being upvoted? Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68507899/edit), please? Thanks in advance.