# Flutter Range Error : Invalid value: ...., Inclusive: -1

Tags: android, dart, flutter

What does "Inclusive: -1" mean in a Range Error
 `RangeError (index): Invalid Value: Not    in range 0..6, inclusive: -1`

Note: index is the argument from

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context,index) => Widget,
)
```

Comment: could you put your code?

Answer (score 7):

The misleading comma is causing you to misparse the error message.  The "inclusive" part is meant to describe the range, not the invalid value.  That is, the error would have been better written as:

`RangeError (index): Invalid Value: -1 not in range 0..6 (inclusive)`

or

`RangeError (index): Invalid Value: -1 not in range [0, 6]`

Somewhere you're passing -1 as an index into a list that has 7 elements.

(https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/29586 requests that the error message be improved.)

Comment: You say `inclusive -1` does not describe the invalid value, but then you go on to say you must be passing the value -1 somewhere...which is the value it does not like...hence it in fact IS the invalid value??

Comment: @Hasen: Read my answer more carefully.  I'm trying to explain that the term "inclusive" is describing the expected *range*, not the invalid value of -1.

Comment: As far as I can see it explains both, the expected range is 0..6, the invalid value is -1....?

Comment: @Hasen ["Inclusive" (and "exclusive") has a specific meaning for mathematical ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010041/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclusive-and-inclusive-when-describing-number-ranges/39010077).

Comment: The inclusive part is in fact the invalid value `inclusive: -1`...since you say he must be passing through -1 which is triggering the error and hence the invalid value. It is a really weird way to write it,I admit,  but that's clearly what it's saying here.

Comment: @Hasen No, the "inclusive" part is indicating that `6` would be a valid value. The "inclusive" adjective has *nothing* to do with `-1`. in the error message.

Comment: ??? Not sure what you're reading. It says `inclusive: -1` ? It doesn't says `inclusive: 6`. The range description is BEFORE the `inclusive` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199605/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-hasen).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by going to the projects root directory and running the command

```
flutter clean
```

... I was experiencing the issue on iOS.