# Why does my media query revert to base styling at breakpoint width:991 px if I have specified @media(min-width: 768) and (max-width: 991px) {...}?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would be very grateful for some assistance with the following.

I have defined the media queries as follows:

/*****base styles -- mobile first****/ for mobile

@media (min-width:768px ) and (max-width:991px) {...} for tablet

@media (min-width: 992px) {...} for desktop

At the breakpoint of width: 991px the rendering reverts to the base style for just that value and at 992px displays the desktop version correctly.

Why is this happening and how can I fix the bug at 991px width?

```css
/***********base styles - mobile first****************/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.section {
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.description {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#title1 {
  background-color: #D59898;
}

#title2 {
  background-color: #C14543;
}

#title3 {
  background-color: #E5D198;
}


/*******medium device only************/

@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  h1 {
    width: 90%;
    left: 35px;
  }
  .section {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    left: 35px;
  }
  #section3 {
    clear: both;
    width: 90%;
  }
  #section1 {
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
}


/*******large device only************/

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .section {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
  }
  #section1 {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Module 2 Solution</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div>
    <section id="section1" class="section">
      <div id="title1" class="title">Chicken</div>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est velit, fermentum in maximus ut, venenatis a massa. Nunc eu quam purus. Quisque semper nulla in urna bibendum efficitur. Sed consequat mi eget dolor accumsan, tempus sagittis
        leo accumsan. Donec id ex nibh. Etiam luctus mi eget mauris semper pretium. Mauris ornare leo ut elit efficitur, nec tempus justo fringilla. Mauris lorem justo, accumsan eu malesuada sed, lacinia at libero. Aenean commodo nec velit vitae molestie.
        Fusce vel leo augue. </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="section">
      <div id="title2" class="title">Beef</div>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est velit, fermentum in maximus ut, venenatis a massa. Nunc eu quam purus. Quisque semper nulla in urna bibendum efficitur. Sed consequat mi eget dolor accumsan, tempus sagittis
        leo accumsan. Donec id ex nibh. Etiam luctus mi eget mauris semper pretium. Mauris ornare leo ut elit efficitur, nec tempus justo fringilla. Mauris lorem justo, accumsan eu malesuada sed, lacinia at libero. Aenean commodo nec velit vitae molestie.
        Fusce vel leo augue.</div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" class="section">
      <div id="title3" class="title">Sushi</div>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque est velit, fermentum in maximus ut, venenatis a massa. Nunc eu quam purus. Quisque semper nulla in urna bibendum efficitur. Sed consequat mi eget dolor accumsan, tempus sagittis
        leo accumsan. Donec id ex nibh. Etiam luctus mi eget mauris semper pretium. Mauris ornare leo ut elit efficitur, nec tempus justo fringilla. Mauris lorem justo, accumsan eu malesuada sed, lacinia at libero. Aenean commodo nec velit vitae molestie.
        Fusce vel leo augue.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the max-width value is [non-inclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010041/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclusive-and-inclusive-when-describing-number-ranges). I could be wrong though. This might make sense, because widths can technically be fractions of a pixel, e.g. 991.5px

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug with browsers' interpretation of @media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637584/bug-with-browsers-interpretation-of-media-queries)

Comment: There was a deleted answer, but it would have fixed the issue: remove the `max-width` - since you do not need it - *unless* you are specifically targeting an element that **only** changes in that breakpoint. Even then, then you won't need the larger `min-width: 992px` since you would want it to go back to default styles.

Comment: Does not answer your question. But you normal want to void `max-width` in media queries whenever possible. At a breakpoint you want to add complexity to the layout, which normally just means that you overwrite certain properties of a previous breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser can fail on calculating max value in case there is some scaling on the page (could be related to high DPI screen usage). There is a well-known workaround used in Bootstrap for example

```
// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }
```

> Why subtract .02px? Browsers don’t currently support range context queries, so we work around the limitations of min- and max- prefixes and viewports with fractional widths (which can occur under certain conditions on high-dpi devices, for instance) by using values with higher precision.

You can read about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#max-width)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is fine at exaclty 991px as max-width is inclusive.

But what happens between 991px and 992px? You haven't told it how to style in that range so it goes back to the basic settings.

As max-width and min-width are inclusive you could have:

```
@media (min-width:768px ) and (max-width:992px) {...} for tablet

@media (min-width: 992px) {...} for desktop
```

OR

```
@media (min-width:768px ) and (max-width:991px) {...} for tablet

@media (min-width: 991px) {...} for desktop
```

depending on exactly where you believe a desktop width starts.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
}

/*for tablet*/
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px) {
  body {
    background: pink;
  }
}

/*for desktop*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background: cyan;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that. However, we have been instructed not to overlap inclusive margins. I am quite a newbie, literally 2 days of CSS under my belt. It is at the exact breakpoint of 991 that it reverts to base-styling:/

Comment: Hi, interesting, I can’t think why that instruction would be made, however as it has been you will have to go with the decimal places solution, although that still leaves a gap in coverage.

Comment: Yes, that actually solves things nicely. Thank you!